# How fdupes can preserve second file

Tags: linux, console, fdupes

Can I preserve second files in list, when works with fdupes?

> fpupes -N -r .

Preserve first files in list, but I need save the SECOND files.
I have about 2000 duplicates and type for each 2 in prompt

> fdupes -d -r .

Is to hard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with fdupes. But you can use fdupes to find the dupes and remove the first one yourself like this:

```
fdupes -rn .|awk 'BEGIN{first=1} (first){print;first=0} /^$/{first=1}'
```

This will print out all the first files found by fdupes, which you then can delete with:

```
command | while read file
do
    rm "$file"
done
```

Not tested, watch out!

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse the order in which the files are displayed with the `-i` option.

From the man page:

```
       -o --order=WORD
              order files according to WORD: time - sort by mtime, name - sort by filename

       -i --reverse
              reverse order while sorting
```

So for you

```
fdupes -N -i -r .
```

should work.

Comment: This works. I had tried sorting with `-o name` before. It sorted on output but did not delete according to the sorted output.

Answer (score 0):

Use [rmlint](https://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/); it has heaps of options for [deciding which file to delete](https://rmlint.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#original-detection-selection).